# SimpleInjector, OWIN and ASP.Net MVC integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, simple-injector

According to the SimpleInjector [documentation](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/owinintegration.html), we can define a Scope that will live during the OWIN request like this.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
    app.Use(async (context, next) => {
        using (container.BeginExecutionContextScope()) {
            await next();
        }
    });
}
```

However, calling container.GetCurrentExecutionContextScope() always returns null when it is called inside a ASP.Net controller's action.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public void MyAction()
    {
      // Here scope is always null
       var scope = Container.GetCurrentExecutionContextScope();
    }
```

I thought it should not be null as the controller action call is inside the scope of an OWIN request ..

Need some clarifications from experts here .. :)

Thanks

Comment: For MVC , the controller is inside the scope of the webrequest (see http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mvcintegration.html). What would you like to achieve by doing this ?

Comment: I'd like to share same instances of objects ( instantiated by SimpleInjector ) between OWIN pipeline and MVC actions (that I thought should be included in the lifetime of a OWIN request but I perhaps miss some informations)

Comment: As Thomas has already been asked, *"What would you like to achieve by doing this?"*

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the OWIN pipeline stuff runs within the web request as well, so the most suited lifestyle is the WebRequestLifestyle.

Comment: @qujck I'm trying to integrate Identity Framework with a DI container (SimpleInjector for my case) and I need to share some instances of objects initialized via OWIN and the DI container.

Comment: @Steven I tried to use this lifestyle also but same result .. :-/

Comment: Could it be that your Configure method is never called and your delegate therefore never registered?

Comment: Or could it be that your MVC controllers do not run through the OWIN pipeline?

Comment: It's possible but how to be sure ? My Configure method is called, I tested it.

Comment: Set a break point on the line `await next();` and inside the controller and see if the first breakpoint got hit.

Comment: According to the debugger, the controller's action call run through the OWIN pipeline .. but still the SimpleInjector execution context is not transmitted from OWIN to the Controller.

Comment: Have you set up the MVC dependency resolver to use the same container instance [`DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));`](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mvcintegration.html)?

Comment: Yes, I have set up all the plumbing ..

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the `Container` property that you call inside your controller points to a different container instance than what is used in the Owin pipeline. An execution context scope is specific to a specific container instance.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

First, please update your Simple Injector.

Documentation to integrate with OWIN: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/owinintegration.html

ASP.NET MVC: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvcintegration.html